# Convertin string of list to list of floats [pandas]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

when importing in pandas the data looks like that:

```
>>> BOM.PriceQty['substrate']
'[200.0, 300.0, 500.0]'
```

how do I convert it to list of floats?
tried convert_objact:

```
>>> BOM.PriceQty['substrate'].convert_object(convert_numeric=True)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute
>   'convert_object'

Thanks!

Comment: it already looks like a list of floats, what does `type(BOM.PriceQty['substrate'][0])` show?

Comment: It seems like a string representing a list, in that case you have to evaluate the string: `eval(BOM.PriceQty['substrate'])`

Comment: It's a string that looks like a list of floats. The quick&dirty solution would be to pass the string to `eval`. However, [it may not be a good idea to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/3005167).

Comment: type(BOM.PriceQty['substrate'][0]) shows <class 'str'>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would nicely convert a string representing a list of floats to an actual list of floats:

```
s = '[200.0, 300.0, 500.0]'
l = [float(x.strip(' []')) for x in s.split(',')]
```

The `strip` function removes any `' '`, `'['`, and `']'` characters resulting from the split.

Result:

```
In [1]: l
Out[1]: [200.0, 300.0, 500.0]
```

If you want to apply this transformation to the entire column, `apply` it as a `lambda` function:

```
BOM.PriceQty.apply(lambda s: [float(x.strip(' []')) for x in s.split(',')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use literal eval as follows:

```
from ast import literal_eval

BOM.PriceQty['substrate'] = BOM.PriceQty['substrate'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(str(x)))
```

str(x) is an added protection to avoid exceptions if the input data is a list. You can remove it if the column value is always a string